# Run cron job only if it isn't already running

Tags: linux, bash, cron, watchdog

I'm trying to set up a cron job as a sort of watchdog for a daemon that I've created. If the daemon errors out and fails, I want the cron job to periodically restart it... I'm not sure how possible this is, but I read through a couple of cron tutorials and couldn't find anything that would do what I'm looking for...

My daemon gets started from a shell script, so I'm really just looking for a way to run a cron job ONLY if the previous run of that job isn't still running.

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/851872/825757), which did provide a solution for what I'm trying to do using lock files, not I'm not sure if there is a better way to do it...

Answer (score 129, accepted):

I do this for a print spooler program that I wrote, it's just a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep doctype.php ; then
        exit 0
else
        /home/user/bin/doctype.php >> /home/user/bin/spooler.log &
        #mailing program
        /home/user/bin/simplemail.php "Print spooler was not running...  Restarted." 
        exit 0
fi
```

It runs every two minutes and is quite effective.  I have it email me with special information if for some reason the process is not running.

Comment: not a very safe solution, though, what if there are other process that matches the search you did in grep? rsanden's answer prevents that sort of problem using a pidfile.

Comment: This wheel was already invented somewhere else :)
E.g., http://serverfault.com/a/82863/108394

Comment: Instead of `grep -v grep | grep doctype.php` you can do `grep [d]octype.php`.

Comment: Note that there's no need for the `&` if it is cron running the script.

Comment: This is an EXCELLENT solution. Works like a charm and if you include the fully qualified path in the program name `grep` searches for, then it is unique. a minor improvement may be to add `--quiet` option on the rightmost `grep`.

Answer (score 184):

Use `flock`.  It's new.  It's better.

Now you don't have to write the code yourself.  Check out more reasons here: https://serverfault.com/a/82863

```
/usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/my.lockfile /usr/local/bin/my_script
```

Comment: I also created a nice cron template gist here: https://gist.github.com/jesslilly/315132a59f749c11b7c6

Comment: `setlock`, `s6-setlock`, `chpst`, and `runlock` in their non-blocking modes are alternatives that are available on more than just Linux.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475580/5132

Comment: Does flock only with with scripts or will it also work with binaries like ansible-pull?

Comment: @majorgear it will execute anything, but usually I see people running a script so they can set environment.

Comment: Thanks. I have Ansible-pull running every 10 minutes to keep my server configurations up to date. I added "flock -on /tmp/ansible-pull.lock " in front of the command and it's working to prevent duplicate instances from running.

Comment: I got Permission denied while it runs normally without flock, any ideas?

Comment: @KarimSamir you should click the Ask Question button and ask a separate question.

Answer (score 65):

As others have stated, writing and checking a PID file is a good solution. Here's my bash implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "$HOME/tmp"
PIDFILE="$HOME/tmp/myprogram.pid"

if [ -e "${PIDFILE}" ] && (ps -u $(whoami) -opid= |
                           grep -P "^\s*$(cat ${PIDFILE})$" &> /dev/null); then
  echo "Already running."
  exit 99
fi

/path/to/myprogram > $HOME/tmp/myprogram.log &

echo $! > "${PIDFILE}"
chmod 644 "${PIDFILE}"
```

Comment: +1 Using a pidfile it's probably much safer than grepping for a running program with the same name.

Comment: /path/to/myprogram & > $HOME/tmp/myprogram.log & ?????? did you perhaps mean /path/to/myprogram >> $HOME/tmp/myprogram.log &

Comment: Shouldn't the file be removed when the script finishes? Or am I missing something very obvious?

Comment: @matteo: I prefer not appending, because I run these for years. Appending is fine if that's what you want.

Comment: @Hamzahfrq: Do you mean the PID file? I don't see any benefit to removing it, because you can't rely on that outcome (you still have to account for the corner case when it wouldn't be removed anyway). Predictable behavior is better.

Comment: Could you please explain how this script is working? I have modified it to generate the PID file every time it runs and remove it before exiting. So, it checks in the beginning and exits if the file exists. The PID file is removed on each reboot in case it is present there. But I think you r script has some other way to handle it

Comment: @Hamzahfrq there was an extra & before the > that's what was confusing; I notice you removed it. Makes sense both to append or not of course.

Comment: @matteo: Yes, you're right. I had fixed that in my notes years ago but forgot to update it here. Worse, I missed it in your comment too, noticing only "`>`" versus "`>>`". Sorry about that.

Comment: @Hamzahfrq: Here's how it works: The script first checks to see if the PID file exists ("`[ -e "${PIDFILE}" ]`". If it does not, then it will start the program in the background, write its PID to a file ("`echo $! > "${PIDFILE}"`"), and exit. If the PID file instead does exist, then the script will check your own processes ("`ps -u $(whoami) -opid=`") and see if you're running one with the same PID ("`grep -P "^\s*$(cat ${PIDFILE})$"`"). If you're not, then it will start the program as before, overwrite the PID file with the new PID, and exit. I see no reason to modify the script; do you?

Comment: The PID approach was chosen, I think in case the program name appeared elsewhere in PS. Isn't there a risk that a PID will be reused by the OS and result in a false match? Deletion of the calling PID file would fix it, but it's a little tricky to do in the scope of the this wrapper script. You may need an internal wrapper script to call the program and delete the PID file when done.

If you do go for the original approach though and lock by program name but also by username, then at least the user has control over the locking credential.

Answer (score 58):

It's suprising that no one mentioned about [run-one](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/run-one). I've solved my problem with this.

```
 apt-get install run-one
```

then add `run-one` before your crontab script

```
*/20 * * * * * run-one python /script/to/run/awesome.py
```

Check out [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/145999) askubuntu SE answer. You can find link to a detailed information there as well.

Comment: What's important to mention is that *this tool is available out of the box in Ubuntu* 20 (and maybe the versions prior as well)

Comment: This was a huge help

Comment: A portable rewrite for Debian, BSD and likely other *nix as well is available from here https://github.com/Freaky/run-one

Answer (score 28):

Don't try to do it via cron. Have cron run a script no matter what, and then have the script decide if the program is running and start it if necessary (note you can use Ruby or Python or your favorite scripting language to do this)

Comment: The classic way is to read a PID file that the service creates when it starts, check if the process with that PID is still running, and restart if not.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do it as a one-liner directly in your crontab:

```
* * * * * [ `ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep <command>` -eq 0 ] && <command>
```

Comment: not very safe, what if there are other commands that matches the search for grep?

Comment: This could also be written as 

* * * * * [ `ps -ef|grep [c]ommand` -eq 0 ] && <command>

where wrapping the first letter of your command in brackets excludes it from the grep results.

Comment: I had to use the following syntax: `[ "$(ps -ef|grep [c]ommand|wc -l)" -eq 0 ] && <command>`

Comment: This is hideous.  `[ $(grep something | wc -l) -eq 0 ]` is a really roundabout way to write `! grep -q something`.  So you want simply `ps -ef | grep '[c]ommand' || command`

Comment: (Also, as an aside, if you really wanted to actually count the number of matching lines, that's `grep -c`.)

Answer (score 9):

The way I am doing it when I am running php scripts is:

## The crontab:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/php/script.php &
```

## The php code:

```
<?php
if (shell_exec('ps aux | grep ' . __FILE__ . ' | wc  -l') > 1) {
    exit('already running...');
}
// do stuff
```

This command is searching in the system process list for the current php filename
 if it exists the line counter (wc -l) will be greater then one because the search command itself containing the filename

so if you running php crons add the above code to the start of your php code and it will run only once.

Comment: This is what I needed as all the other solutions required installing something on the client server, which I don't have access to do.

Answer (score 6):

As a follow up to Earlz answer, you need a wrapper script that creates a $PID.running file when it starts, and delete when it ends. The wrapper script calls the script you wish to run. The wrapper is necessary in case the target script fails or errors out, the pid file gets deleted..

Comment: Oh cool... I never thought about using a wrapper... I couldn't figure out a way to do it using lock files because I couldn't guarantee that the file would get deleted if the daemon errored out... A wrapper would work perfectly, I'm going to give jjclarkson's solution a shot, but I'll do this if that doesn't work...

Answer (score 5):

With `lockrun` you don't need to write a wrapper script for your cron job.  http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/lockrun.html

Answer (score 4):

```
# one instance only (works unless your cmd has 'grep' in it)
ALREADY_RUNNING_EXIT_STATUS=0
bn=`basename $0`
proc=`ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep "$bn" | grep -v " $$ "`
[ $? -eq 0 ] && {
    pid=`echo $proc | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo "$bn already running with pid $pid"
    exit $ALREADY_RUNNING_EXIT_STATUS
}
```

UPDATE .. better way using flock:

```
/usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/your-app.lock /path/your-app args
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to use an existing tool such as [monit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/monit), it will monitor and auto restart processes. There is more information available [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-monitor-and-restart-linux-unix-service.html). It should be easily available in most distributions.

Comment: Every answer except this one answers the surface question "How can my cron job make sure it only runs one instance?" when the real question is "How can I keep my process running in the face of restarts?", and the correct answer is indeed to not use cron, but instead a process supervisor like monit. Other options include [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [s6](https://www.skarnet.org/software/s6/) or, if your distribution already uses systemd, just creating a systemd service for the process that needs to be kept alive.

Answer (score 2):

[This one](https://github.com/patrickmn/one.sh/blob/master/one.sh) never failed me:

**one.sh**:

```
LFILE=/tmp/one-`echo "$@" | md5sum | cut -d\  -f1`.pid
if [ -e ${LFILE} ] && kill -0 `cat ${LFILE}`; then
   exit
fi

trap "rm -f ${LFILE}; exit" INT TERM EXIT
echo $$ > ${LFILE}

$@

rm -f ${LFILE}
```

**cron job**:

```
* * * * * /path/to/one.sh <command>
```

Answer (score 2):

Docs: https://www.timkay.com/solo/

> solo is a very simple script (10 lines) that prevents a program from
>   running more than one copy at a time. It is useful with cron to make
>   sure that a job doesn't run before a previous one has finished.

Example

```
* * * * * solo -port=3801 ./job.pl blah blah
```

Comment: This should be higher in the list.  It avoids all the crap that lockfiles involve (stale files, lock reliability that depends on the underlying filesystem (think NFS), race conditions due to non-atomic naïve implementations, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following as an improvement to [rsanden's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7453411/1343535) (I'd post as a comment, but don't have enough reputation...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

PIDFILE="$HOME/tmp/myprogram.pid"

if [ -e "${PIDFILE}" ] && (ps -p $(cat ${PIDFILE}) > /dev/null); then
  echo "Already running."
  exit 99
fi

/path/to/myprogram
```

This avoids possible false matches (and the overhead of grepping), and it suppresses output and relies only on exit status of ps.

Comment: Your `ps` command would match PIDs for other users on the system, not just your own. Adding a "`-u`" to the `ps` command changes the way the exit status works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple custom php is enough to achieve. No need to confuse with shell script.

lets assume you want to run **php /home/mypath/example.php** if not running

Then use following custom php script to do the same job.

create following **/home/mypath/forever.php**

```
<?php
    $cmd = $argv[1];
    $grep = "ps -ef | grep '".$cmd."'";
    exec($grep,$out);
    if(count($out)<5){
        $cmd .= ' > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &';
        exec($cmd,$out);
        print_r($out);
    }
?>
```

Then in your cron add following

```
* * * * * php /home/mypath/forever.php 'php /home/mypath/example.php'
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using pgrep (if available) rather than ps piped through grep if you're going to go that route. Though, personally, I've got a lot of mileage out of scripts of the form

```
while(1){
  call script_that_must_run
  sleep 5
}
```

Though this can fail and cron jobs *are* often the best way for essential stuff. Just another alternative.

Comment: This would just start the daemon over and over again and does not solve the problem mentioned above.