# cannot understand grep in cron job solution

Tags: cron, grep

i was looking at the solution of [Run cron job only if it isn't already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366693/run-cron-job-only-if-it-isnt-already-running) in order to apply it to a similar problem that I have but I cannot understand the

```bash
ps -u $USER -f | grep "[ ]$(cat ${PIDFILE})[ ]"'
```

It appears to be saying check  the end of each line from ps for ' PIDnumber ' but when I look at my ps output the PIDnumber is in column two. I am interpreting the first $ as the regular expression check_end_of_line option.

Answer (score 1):

`$(stuff)` will execute "stuff" (in this case `cat ${PIDFILE}`)

PIDFILE is assumed to be a path to a file, so the whole line is basically looking for any line in the ps output that contains the contents of the "pid file" (`[ ]` adds some spaces on each side of the pid so that if pid file contains '888' it wont match '8888' in the ps output)