# cron script not executing on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I am not a linux expert and I have a problem I do not manage to solve. I am sorry if it is obvious.
I am trying to execute a bash script in a cron table on a raspberry pi, and I don't manage to get it work.
Here is the example script I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games

plouf=$( ps -aux | grep reviews | wc -l)
if [[ "$plouf" == 1 ]] ;
then
    echo "plouf" >> /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/crontest.txt
fi
```

My script in the cron consist in starting a script if there is no progam with review in its name running. To test I am just appending "plouf" to a file. I count the number of line of `ps -aux | grep reviews | wc -l` , and if there in only one line I do append "plouf" in a file.
Here is my crontab:

```
crontab -l


SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
* * * * * sudo /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh
```

The script do work when I do `./ script2.sh` or `/home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh` directly in terminl: it add a "plouf" to the file.

I came across [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working) and tried different possibilities, by setting my path as the path given by `env`, and by explicitly setting the shell in the cron. But still not working.
What I am I doing wrong ?

---

To answer Mark Setchell comment:

```
raspberrypi:~/Documents/french_pain $ sudo /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh
raspberrypi:~/Documents/french_pain $ cat crontest.txt
plouf
```

and cron is running:

```
raspberrypi:~/Documents/french_pain $ pgrep cron
353
```

I manage to do simple jobs like

```
* * * * * /bin/echo "cron works" >> /tmp/file
```

I tried with the direct path to the commands:

```
plouf=$( /bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep 'R CMD.*reviews' | usr/bin/wc -l)
if [[ "$plouf" == 1 ]] ;
then
   /bin/echo "plouf" >> /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/crontest.txt
fi
```

without any luck. The permission for the file:

`-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root         6 juil.  3 23:30 crontest.txt`

I tried deleting it, and did not work either.
help !

Comment: What happens if you do this in the Terminal `sudo /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh`

Comment: it works perfectly, adds a "plouf" to my file

Comment: Try running `type sudo` and adding the full path to `sudo` into your crontab.

Comment: no, it does not work. Removing `sudo ` either.

Comment: Nearly out of ideas! Try adding a blank line at the end of your crontab.

Comment: I did that too, I saw that here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working . It is so frustrating, I don't get it. Thank you for trying

Comment: Last idea... maybe something here https://gist.github.com/satishask/2c892a10144053ba1687ce9cb2748dd5

Comment: thank you for the link. I will try all point.

Comment: It's not clear if the problem is a) your script is not running at all, or b) it is running but cannot produce output. So try making the second line of your script `touch /tmp/ran-at-$SECONDS`

Comment: grepping the output of `ps` is unpredictable -- depending on timing, when you do something like `/bin/ps -aux | /bin/grep 'R CMD.*reviews'`, the `ps` command might or might not print the `grep` command among its output, and the `grep` will match its own entry, adding one to the number of matches. I'd recommend using `pgrep`, which avoids this problem. You can replace the entire pipeline with `plouf=$(pgrep -c 'R CMD.*reviews')`

Comment: @GordonDavisson thank you for pointing that out. It did not solve my problem, but was really worth learning. Thanks

Comment: @MarkSetchell I found a solution finally (see my answer below), so I stopped searching why this was not working. Thank you so much for helping. I learned a lot

Answer (score 1):

I guess you trying this as "pi" user then 'sudo' won't work unless you have allowed nopasswd:all or using a command that is able to handle the password that Sudo requires from stdin in this case. The example below is dangerous since it will not require any password for sudo command anymore but since you wanted to use sudo in cronie:

#### Example 1:

#### With default /etc/sudoers below example will create an empty file:

```
* * * * * sudo ls / > ~/cronietest.txt
```

#### Try add below in /etc/sudoers at bottom (obs: **do not** use pi as username on a rpi):

```
pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

#### Now try again to add below in crontab

```
* * * * * sudo ls / > ~/cronietest.txt
```

#### It works!

#### Example 2:

#### This is more safe, add this to sudoers file for allow 'command' for "pi" user without any password when sudo is executed:

```
pi ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/<command>
```

#### Example 3:

#### Without editing sudoers file, this is another example that will work (this is dangerous since your password is stored in cron file as plaintext)

```
* * * * * echo "password" | sudo -S ls / > ~/cronietest.txt
```

Comment: I wish it was the solution, but calling `* * * * * /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh` (i.e. without `sudo`) in the crontab does not work either, whereas calling `/home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script2.sh` in terminal does work

Comment: Raspbian already allows this by default. Specifically, `/etc/sudoers.d/010_pi-nopasswd` contains "`pi ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`".

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the reason why the sript was not working, but I finally found a way to make it work thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366693/run-cron-job-only-if-it-isnt-already-running): I used shell script instead of bash:
The file `script3.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep 'reviews'; then
      exit 0
else
      echo "plouf" >> /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/crontest.txt
fi
```

together with

```
* * * * * /home/pi/Documents/french_pain/script3.sh
```

in my crontab did the work I wanted.